# Can I acquire cantrips with the Wizard multi-class feat?

Tags: dnd-4e, house-rules, multi-classing

The multiclass feat for wizards in the PHB says you gain a 1st level wizard at-will ability. Now, the cantrips in there are gained *at* first level, and they *are* at-will. I'm guessing that, since they aren't designated as 1st-level specifically, they don't count for the purposes of the feat and thus cannot be gained. Is that right? If so, is there any other way for a non-gnome to gain them? (Not hating on gnomes; I just know they can!)

Also, has anyone allowed this as a house rule? How has it gone?

Comment: So has anyone allowed this as a houserule?

Comment: @Pureferret - I haven't, but personally I wouldn't have any problem giving a multiclass wizard cantrips for a feat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no general way to gain Cantrips as they are Wizard Utility powers with no level.  Without a level they can't be used to substitute for another gained power.

There are a couple other ways besides being a gnome though

- the [Resourceful Magician](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=456) paragon path (Bard) grants the Wizard's Cantrip class feature if the bard possesses the Arcane Initiate feat (Dragon #376)
- [Fey Cantrip](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3653) feat allows Fey creatures to gain 1 cantrip (Heroes of the Feywild)
- [Wild Talent Master](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3247) feat allows you to select 3 Wild Talents which are basically psionic cantrips (Dark Sun Campaign Setting)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Also, thanks for supplying those alternatives. none of them would apply to a dwarven warlock though, so I'll have to look else where for 'cool things' for my character.

Comment: @Pureferret - sorry I didn't have better news for you!

Comment: That's fine, I was hoping you might say..."In that case.." But it's fine :)

Answer (score 8):

While, as others have said, you cannot get the abilities through that specific method. Here is a very simple way to get the cantrips you desire!

From Adventurers Vault, page 135:

```
Hedge Wizard’s Gloves Level 4
With a wave of these patched gloves, you can perform magic
tricks.
Item Slot: Hands 840 gp
Power (At-Will ✦ Arcane, Conjuration): Standard Action.
As the wizard’s mage hand power (PH 158).
Power (At-Will ✦ Arcane): Standard Action. As the
wizard’s prestidigitation power (PH 159).
```

Takes up your hands slot of course, but that's it.  Between these and the other answers, there will be no reason you can't have those abilities no houseruling required.  Enjoy!

Comment: It's important to note that these cost standard actions to activate. But for a thief who wants to douse light sources, there's no better way.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Wizard cantrips do not count as a lv.1 At-Will for the Wizard multiclass feat.

Fey Cantrip

> **Prerequisite:** Fey origin or Fey Bond feat
>   **Benefit:** Choose one wizard cantrip, such as mage hand or prestidigitation. You gain that power.

or you can choose Wild Talent from Dark Sun, which has the same effects at the cantrips but with a psionic fluff to them.